# Responsive Superfish module?

Tags: theming, navigation

I'm trying to make responsive the menu generated by the [superfish](http://drupal.org/project/superfish) module and using the [Omega](http://drupal.org/project/omega) theme by using this appoach:

[Demo](http://mattkersley.com/demos/responsive_menu/) (try resizing your browser)

[Script on Github](https://github.com/mattkersley/Responsive-Menu)

I also found a theme for joomla which include a superfish responsive menu: [here](http://themes.cloudhotelier.com/skeleton/the-grid)

Before wasting time... Is there any other **tested** solution out there?

Comment: I implemented the script but not working properly in Firefox. I'll try a different approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Superfish is now responsive. ;)